# Faces message added in getter method doesn't display in messages component

Tags: jsf, rendering, message

I want to style a cell of a table conditionally. This is easy and works.

```
style="#{zoekOndernemingController.geldigeOnderneming(row) ? '' : 'color: red'}"
```

However, the condition is on the backend as you can see. In the function geldigeOnderneming(Object o) I add a faces message, but this message is not displayed. Is it because there are restrictions when calling backend functions from certain attributes, like style?

I have no idea why it is not displayed, and I also don't know how to debug this. On the internet I cannot find anything about this so any help is greatly appreciated!

PS faces message added like this:

```
public static void addFacesMessage(final FacesMessage fm) {
    final FacesContext ctx = JSFUtils.getFacesContextInstance();
    ctx.addMessage(null, fm);
}
```

It works perfectly in other places...

Comment: Yes, namely: <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true" escape="false" />. Are you suggesting if i move the messages component after the component containing that EL expression, it will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically trying to add a faces message during render response. It will be too late if the message(s) component was already rendered for long at that point.

```
<h:messages />
...
<h:someComponent someAttribute="#{bean.someMethodWhichAddsMessage()}" />
```

It will "work" if you swap around the components.